# How to make authorization using SQLite , MVVM in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm

I have 2 independent projects, registration and the main window with a login,I made binding to the same SQLite file.
The user registers everything is fine, but now I need that the login would work correctly. How to extract the user from BD and to make check whether such user exists and whether the password coincides using MVVM?

I'm start to create 2 classes

```
public class ServiceResult
{
    public bool IsSucceed { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public ServiceResult()
    {
        IsSucceed = true;
    }

    public ServiceResult(string error)
    {
        IsSucceed = false;
        Error = error;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AuthorizationService
{

    public ServiceResult Login(string login,string password)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db= new ApplicationDbContext();
        return new ServiceResult();
    }
}
```

My Register ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    Hashing hashing = new Hashing();
    ApplicationDbContext db;
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get => lastName;
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
        }
    }
    private string login;
    public string Login
    {
        get => login;
        set
        {
            login = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Login));
        }
    }

    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            if (password != value)
            {
                password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
    }
    private string mail;
    public string Mail
    {
        get => mail;
        set
        {
            mail = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Mail));
        }
    }



    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    private RelayCommand registerCommand;
    public RelayCommand RegisterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return registerCommand ??
                (registerCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    var _user = new RegisterUser(Name, LastName, Login, hashing.Encrypt(Password), Mail);
                    db.Users.Add(_user);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

This is Login ViewModel

```
 ApplicationDbContext db;
    IEnumerable<User> users;

    public LoginViewModel(IViewFactory viewFactory, ICore core) : base(viewFactory)
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    private string login;
    public string Login
    {
        get => login;
        set
        {
            login = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Login));
        }
    }
    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get => password;
        set
        {
            password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand addCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
                (addCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                }));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> Users
    {
        get { return users; }
        set
        {
            users = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done , it's was easy )

```
public class AuthorizationService
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ServiceResult Login(string login,string password)
    {
        var listUsers= db.Users.ToList();
        foreach (var item in listUsers)
        {
            if (item.Login == login || item.Password == password)
            {
                return new ServiceResult();
            }
        }
        return new ServiceResult("Wrong Login or Password!");
    }
}
```

and Login ViewModel

```
private RelayCommand loginUser;
    public RelayCommand LoginUser
    {
        get
        {
            return loginUser ??
                (loginUser = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    var result = _authorizationService.Login(Login, hashing.Encrypt(Password));
                }));
        }
    }
```